# Error al iniciar servicio con JBoss

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jboss, jboss-as-7

Estoy trabajando con Hibernate 4.3, JSF 2.0 y JBoss 7.0.1, y al lanzar la vista del proyecto me aparece la siguiente excepción:

```
19:44:23,592 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Ultima.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Ultima.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Ultima.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: only one persistence provider can be packaged with an application [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider, org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
    ... 5 more

19:44:23,804 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "Ultima.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Ultima.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Ultima.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Ultima.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Ultima.Ultima.Ultima.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima ]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Ultima.Ultima.Ultima.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima ]"]}
19:44:24,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Stopped deployment Ultima.war in 369ms
19:44:24,176 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Ultima.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Ultima.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Ultima.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Ultima.Ultima.Ultima.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima ]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Ultima.Ultima.Ultima.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima ]"]}}}
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué me sucede este error?¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Es más urgente que corrijas los graves problemas de edición y formato que esta pregunta presenta o corre el riesgo de ser cerrada. Te recomiendo que visites el centro de ayuda y leas sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración ("¿por qué no funciona este código?") deben incluir cual es el comportamiento deseado, un problema o error específico y el mínimo de código necesario para reproducirlo.

Comment: Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: only one persistence provider can be packaged with an application [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider -->comprueba que no este duplicado, que la declaracion del provider sea correcta para la version de Jboss que utilizas. y pule la pregunta!

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no todos los problemas requieren mostrar código. Este es un problema de despliegue de aplicación, no está asociado al código necesariamente, lo más importante aquí es tener un stacktrace claro y luego, si es necesario, solicitar el código.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Mi motivo de cierre es una copia literal de [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), que claramente indica que esta pregunta es _off-topic_ porque "Algunas preguntas no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías mencionadas". Sí, el usuario expone un problema específico (con el stack trace), pero a la pregunta le falta el comportamiento deseado y al menos la línea de código en la que sucede el error. Esta pregunta no se debería haber reabierto hasta que se hubiese editado al ser de muy baja calidad y off-topic.

Comment: @vrojas en el mensaje de error pone que a los servicios les faltan algunas dependencias (en concreto parece que `jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima`). ¿Podrías revisar que los servicios/módulos especificados en el _stack trace_ tienen todas las dependencias adecuadas y están en los paquetes/subpaquetes/namespaces correctos?¿Está bien escrito eso de `jboss.naming.context.java.module.Ultima.Ultima` o debería ser sólo un `.Ultima` en lugar de dos?

Comment: El error es bastante claro. Al parecer, tienes dos versiones distintas de `hibernate` o en el archivo `persistence.xml` has declarado dos `<provider>`. Ten en cuenta que actualmente, el proveedor correcto es `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Pues el error, es claro, te esta indicando que tienes mas de un proveedor de persistencia, si estas configurando spring por xml, deberías compartirnos tu xml, estoy de acuerdo que necesitamos mas detalles, como configuras hibernate?
Es una aplicación con spring?.

Y tambien puede ser si estas utilizando wildfly un error de dependencias.

Intenta agregando la siguiente dependencia a tu pom

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jipijapa</groupId>
 <artifactId>jipijapa-hibernate4-3</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```